# Positional arguments in string formatting: str.format vs f-string

Tags: python, string, format, python-3.6, positional-argument

When trying out some features with the new (and awesome) python 3 [literal string interpolation](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/), I found this weird difference.

For example, using the old `str.format`, I can format integers with a dynamic number of digits like this:

```
>>> d = 5
>>> N = 3
>>> '{:0{N}d}'.format(d, N=N)
'005'
```

But when I try the equivalent using literal strings, I get an error:

```
>>> f'{:0{N}d}'
SyntaxError: f-string: empty expression not allowed
```

Only by swapping the order of the arguments do I get the correct formatting

```
>>> f'{d:0{N}}'
'005'
```

This struck me as odd since I assumed I could just swap to f-strings without modifying my strings, only the calls.

What are the syntactic differences between `str.format` and f-string? And why does this example differ slightly?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You've misunderstood what `'{:0{N}d}'.format(d, N=N)` does. The `d` in the format spec doesn't refer to the variable `d`; it means print an integer in base 10. Python matches that field with the `d` argument positionally.

When you try that with an f-string, `f'{:0{N}d}'`, f-strings have no positional arguments. Python doesn't know what to format for that field. You need to fix your original bug and place `d` in front of the `:` so Python knows it's supposed to format `d` there.

For reference, the correct version with `format` would have been `'{d:0{N}}'.format(d=d, N=N)`.

Comment: Well that was a simple resolution! Thank you.